# How to use Decimal64 DPD with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, decimal

I have been trying to figure out how to integrate [Decimal Floating Types](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Decimal-Float.html) with GCC 10.2.0.

I built gcc with `--enable-decimal-float=dpd` and `--with-backend=libdecnumber` flags, and specified `DFP_ENABLE=1` env var. The logs show decimalNNN being built into gcc, and I am able to successfully compile the following:

```
#define __STDC_WANT_DEC_FP__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main () {
  _Decimal64 d = 3.1415DD;
}
```

Next, I'm trying to figure out how to / where to get the supported libdfp math functions working with _Decimal64. I've grep'ed through the header files in gcc (which was built with the flags mentioned above), and I cannot find any such functions.

Also, I've looked into the [libdfp](https://github.com/libdfp/libdfp) project itself, and tried to built it, but it seems it's only compilable in Linux (I'm on MacOS).

Searching stackoverflow and github, I find indication that some people have this working, but I'm stuck.

What am I missing? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note that this requires some support from `libc`, specifically `glibc` [which macOS doesn't use]. Also, `libdfp` is stable [because it hasn't been modified since 2010--per comment on github page]. So, you may be SOL. If you have your heart set on this, then, so be it. But, if you can take a step back, what functionality does this provide that you _need_ (e.g. does rounding differently)? If you want higher precision, `gmp` (GNU multiple precision arithemetic) library may be of use. See: https://gmplib.org/ It has [I presume] a macOS port.

Comment: From the github page, there is the `DPD` format [from IBM]. Even before I saw this, I was thinking that it was similar to IBM's [on their mainframes] "packed decimal" format which have had H/W instructions for packed decimal arithmetic since the 1960s. IBM's instructions allowed variable length decimal number up to 256(?) digits. They were used by banking S/W that needed exact values without truncation (e.g. an alternative to `uint32_t`). It's not too hard to create functions that implement this. Although you might be reinventing the wheel, it might be less work than trying to port the lib.